# Tensorflow Build iOS sh Error

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow

I am using XCode8.3 and also have a XCode9 beta, My XCode select 8.3 as default.

When I build Tensorflow iOS sh script

./tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_ios.sh

Got an error like this:

**clang: error: no such sysroot directory: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk' [-Werror,-Wmissing-sysroot]
make: *** [common.o] Error 1**

Yes, I did not have iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk, but I have 9.1 and 10.3 simulator. 
How to fix this issue? should I download the iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk or where can I set for this option?

Thanks for your great support in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into '[compile_nsync.sh](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/compile_nsync.sh)' file.
They have hardcoded sdks, `$xcode/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.0.sdk`
 probably you should change all appearances to current sdk  `$IPHONESIMULATOR_SYSROOT`

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Works for me.